# When was the word "scroll" first used as a verb?

Tags: phrases, verbs, terminology, history

We all know that a scroll is a roll of parchment used in ancient times. A scroll can be **rolled** up or down, and that must have been the metaphor the creator of the computer-term "scroll" had in mind.

But in English, is it acceptable to say you can **scroll** (verb) a scroll (noun) up and down? As far as I know it should be "**roll** up/down" in this context, so how is it that we use "scroll" as a verb in computer terminology?

When was the word "scroll" first used as a verb, and how is it that we don't rather use the appropriate scroll-metaphor (the object), which would be to **roll**  the page up and down?

Comment: In 1981 for the scrolling computer window sense: [See etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=scroll&allowed_in_frame=0), 1600 for scroll as a verb in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OED’s first recorded use of *scroll* as a verb is in 1606 when it meant ‘to write down in a scroll’. The first use in the sense ‘To roll or curl up’ is in 1868. The first use in a computing context is in 1971. By 1977 it was being used in the sense ‘to move displayed material upwards by scrolling’ and by 1979 ‘to move through text on a screen by scrolling’.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! So is it valid in modern English to "scroll" (verb) up a scroll? Or is it still roll? And if it's not too much trouble, could you please provide citations for the dates, or direct to somewhere I can find them?

Comment: @Herman: For this kind of detail, you really need to subscribe to the OED: http://www.oed.com/.

Comment: Scrolling panoramas became popular in the US in the 1850s (and in Asia much, much earlier). See, e.g. this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_panorama). I wonder whether the verb *scroll* was used to describe them at that time?